# Is there a way to adapt single-processed xor alghorithm to multiprocess?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, xor

```
def _internal_xor_operation(args):
    key = args[0]
    message = args[1]
    key = bytes(key, "UTF-8")
    repetitions = 1 + (len(message) // len(key))
    key *= repetitions
    key = key[:len(message)]
    return bytes([b ^ k for b, k in zip(message, key)])
```

This is a alghorithm for XORing a message. Now, can I speed the process up bu using multiple threads?

Comment: No CPU bound operation in python can be sped up by using multiple *threads*, the python GIL prevents that (at least as of today). You can try to use multiple *processes* to possibly obtain a speedup, but the overhead of using multiple process can be significant and may dwarf any gains you would otherwise obtain. In this case the the parts of the message itself must also be communicated to each process, an operation which is of the same order as the computation you are trying to parallelize. Perhaps shared memory can help, you'd have to try it and see.

Comment: I was talking about processes